# Python Selenium How to get anchor tag href value only if anchor tag contains certain attribute value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

i want to get GitHub repository links from [GitHub search results](https://github.com/topics/ios). right now, my code gets links of both username and repository. how do i get only the repository links by targeting anchor tag attribute values.

my code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

path = "C:\programs\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
url = 'https://github.com/topics/flutter-apps'

driver.get(url)

links_list = []

headings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('f3')


for heading in headings:
    links = heading.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for l in links:
        links_list.append(l.get_attribute('href'),)


print(links_list)
```

this is the code i want to get links from.

```html
    <h1 class="f3 text-gray text-normal lh-condensed">
      <a data-hydro-click="{&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;explore.click&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:{&quot;click_context&quot;:&quot;REPOSITORY_CARD&quot;,&quot;click_target&quot;:&quot;OWNER&quot;,&quot;click_visual_representation&quot;:&quot;REPOSITORY_OWNER_HEADING&quot;,&quot;actor_id&quot;:49521558,&quot;record_id&quot;:484656,&quot;originating_url&quot;:&quot;https://github.com/topics/ios&quot;,&quot;user_id&quot;:49521558}}"
        data-hydro-click-hmac="7b69680b468dda1b4e10ddab19c8034fd4c530bc57957662d8be320d79cc38f1"
        data-ga-click="Explore, go to repository owner, location:explore feed" href="/vsouza">
        vsouza
      </a> /
      <a data-hydro-click="{&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;explore.click&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:{&quot;click_context&quot;:&quot;REPOSITORY_CARD&quot;,&quot;click_target&quot;:&quot;REPOSITORY&quot;,&quot;click_visual_representation&quot;:&quot;REPOSITORY_NAME_HEADING&quot;,&quot;actor_id&quot;:49521558,&quot;record_id&quot;:21700699,&quot;originating_url&quot;:&quot;https://github.com/topics/ios&quot;,&quot;user_id&quot;:49521558}}"
        data-hydro-click-hmac="c38ef14c5a72214b8e946bde857c36653301cb96a15a6b1108242526485221b8"
        data-ga-click="Explore, go to repository, location:explore feed" href="/vsouza/awesome-ios" class="text-bold">
        awesome-ios
      </a>
    </h1>
```

between the two anchor elements i want to get href value of anchor tag which has this attribute and value `data-ga-click="Explore, go to repository, location:explore feed"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get such specific link you have pass this `data-ga-click` attribute in your `xpath` to get unique result.

```
for heading in headings:
   links = heading.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@data-ga-click="Explore, go to repository, location:explore feed"]')
   for l in links:
        links_list.append(l.get_attribute('href'))
```

Or Css Selector.

```
for heading in headings:
   links = heading.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[data-ga-click="Explore, go to repository, location:explore feed"]')
   for l in links:
        links_list.append(l.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want only the a tags with that value inside heading. You need to use the . for child elements and use the data attribute value.

```
heading.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@data-ga-click="Explore, go to repository owner, location:explore feed"]')
```